# texelFetch from CubeMap

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, shader

In OpenGL/GLSL, is it possible to do texelFetch from cubemaps? Something along the lines of:

```
color = texelFetch(cubemapsampler,texCoordi, side);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there is no overload for texelFetch and so it appear impossible.

However, you can manipulate the direction vector used for lookup to obtain the same result[*]:

```
vec3 generate_cubemap_coord(in vec2 txc, in int face)
{
  vec3 v;
  switch(face)
  {
    case 0: v = vec3( 1.0, -txc.x, txc.y); break; // +X
    case 1: v = vec3(-1.0,  txc.x, txc.y); break; // -X
    case 2: v = vec3( txc.x,  1.0, txc.y); break; // +Y
    case 3: v = vec3(-txc.x, -1.0, txc.y); break; // -Y
    case 4: v = vec3(txc.x, -txc.y,  1.0); break; // +Z
    case 5: v = vec3(txc.x,  txc.y, -1.0); break; // -Z
  }
  return normalize(v);
}

color = texture(cubemapsampler, generate_cubemap_coord(texCoordf, side));
```

[*] *The code presented is meant to represent the concept and it may cointain errors.*

Comment: The good thing about texelFetch is that you can use gl_FragCoord.xy directly for post processing shaders. I guess I can translate gl_FragCoord.xy to txc, but that will probably yield a performance loss. Any ideas for easily doing post processing on cube map textures?